# Turning a git branch name into a valid docker image tag

Tags: git, docker

Part of our CI/CD workflow tags Docker images with the git branch's name. However, the set of valid characters for docker tags is smaller than the set of valid characters for a git branch name.

As a very simple example, the branch name `bugfix/my_awesome_feature` is not a valid tag:

```
docker build . -t image_name:$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Fails with the error that it is "not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format".

Same with more complicated branch names: `fix/bug#123`, `pr@123`, etc....

**What's the best way to turn a git branch name into a valid docker tag?** Ignoring or replacing all invalid characters is fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Docker tag does not allow most of the special character except `-,_,.`.

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase
> letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not
> start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128
> characters.

[docker valid image tags](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description:%7E:text=A%20tag%20name%20must%20be,a%20maximum%20of%20128%20characters.)

So you can replace all special character with `-`. in your Branch name.

```
docker build . -t image_name:$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-/g')
```

So the following branch will become

```
fix/bug#123 -> fix-bug-123  
pr@123 -> pr-123
```

You can replace `-` with **underscores, periods and dashes**

```
#to use `_`
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/g'
```

Comment: I ended up keeping *only* the allowed characters (alphanumeric, dots, dashes, and underscores) with: `sed 's/[^[:alnum:]\.\_\-]/-/g'`. Everything else gets converted to a dash here.

Comment: how to make it in GitLab ci/cd?

Comment: @catscoolzhyk in Gitlib you can use `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` instead of branch name to avoid workaround. "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME lowercased, shortened to 63 bytes, and with everything except 0-9 and a-z replaced with -. No leading / trailing -. Use in URLs, host names and domain names" https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Answer (score 17):

When using GitLab CI, you can use a predefined variable `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`, description:

> `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` lowercased, shortened to 63 bytes, and with everything except `0-9` and `a-z` replaced with `-`. No leading / trailing -. Use in URLs, host names and domain names.

[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)